# EntityFramework Seed a table immediately after creation

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Code First Migrations and ran into an issue where I created a new lookup table (Lookup) and established a required foreign key relationship with it (Table).

The (Table) already has records in it, so after adding the column I am backfilling the existing records (before the AddForeignKey method) with a default value to satisfy the required field requirement.

I have the (Lookup) table filling with Data in the Seed process.

The issue I am having is that when I run my code first migrations, I am getting a foreign key constraint error because in the migration Up code I am creating the foreign key relationship with the (Lookup) table and backfilling the records using the Sql command.  But since the Seed method hasn't run yet, the (Lookup) table has no values in it, so the constraint fails.

Is there a way to execute that Fill without being redundant with the code in the Configuration.Seed method?

Comment: In my experience, I had to first create the column in one migration, then update/seed the data, then perform a second migration to add the constraint (in my case, I think it was making my new column not nullable).  If there is a one-step way to do it, I would be happy to learn, too!

Comment: I haven't found a one-step way to do it yet.  What I decided to do is juse use the Sql statement in my migration code to handle the backfilling and lookup table fill before establishing the foreign key relationship.  The seed method still runs as it's supposed to, it just currently doesnt have anything to do because the data is already in the lookup table.  One benefit that I noticed was that the seed will still be the most up to date record because the addorupdate command will update things accordingly.  I still wish there was one step way to do it, but this works for now.